# Any angle divides a plane into two regions

Tags: geometry, intuition

I am studying Euclidian geometry and I noticed that any angle divides a plane into two regions: an inside and an outside. Is there a need for a proof of this (something along the lines of Jordan theorem), or is it just "obvious"?

Browsing the internet, I came across a following simpler version: any line divides a plane into two regions. Maybe someone will find it relevant.

My current understanding is that the PSA plays a key role in this sort of thing. Unless you are doing it the analytic geometry way, in which case the PSA must be somehow already "coded in" ...I think.

Comment: The word "obvious" has little place in Mathematics. For example, Russell & Whitehead took over 200 pages of advanced symbol-shuffling to get to a proof that $1+1=2$. This level of rigour is certainly impractical, though, so it depends on your circumstances.

Comment: I meant derivation from Euclids axioms kind of rigour.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to find a way to define regions.

Comment: That "kind" of rigour is rigour nonetheless. Your circumstances dictate how much detail you need from the axioms at hand. **In principle**, *every* result needs to be established line-by-line, no matter what seems intuitively "obvious". This distinguishes Mathematics from mere guesswork & superstition. However, in practice, not so much; it's a judgment call.

Comment: Ad edit: philosophy? Is that supposed to be an insult? :-D

Comment: @Adam: No: I'm serious. You're asking an instance of how much we can take for granted as "obvious" in proofs. There's a plethora of theories on that :)

Comment: I suppose the question might appeal even to a philosophy major. But I seriously doubt that questions such as this would bother working mathematicians. Or do they?

Comment: @Adam: They might; they certainly *did*: hence the Bourbaki & Hilbert programmes and the work cited above. It defined Mathematics circa 1900. Perhaps I'm not in the best place to explain this to you. Would anyone care to step in? Also: please use `@` then my name to get my attention :)

Comment: Yes I know a thing or two about these developments. What I meant is that todays mathematicians, unless they work in set theory or something have some clearly established level of rigour which they take from other works in their field, or so is my outsider perspective, any one care to correct me?

Comment: @Adam: Well, then, see my second comment; I know. Your question on whether a proof is *needed* won't be resolved without the context such a proof would be in.

Comment: I dont think I can agree with that sentiment. The person answering my question can choose a context himself. I wont be too picky. All I am looking for is some kind of deduction from simpler assumptions. It doesnt even have to be rigorous, just something. So far we have zilch. Except for the hint below from Michael Hoppe, which in its present form is absolutely useless to me.

Comment: @Shaun: How is this about philosophy or foundations of mathematics?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: In light of this question: "**Is there a need for a proof of this** (something along the lines of Jordan theorem), or is it just "obvious"?"

Comment: @Shaun: Doesn't merit either tags.

Comment: @Asaf Karagina: That may be, but those with an interest in this sort of thing (other than yourself) might disagree with you. Adam *might have* disagreed *had* he learned something from my comments above or from what an expert in either of those fields might have to say. Suppose that he had thought a proof wasn't necessary *whatsoever*. Would they still have been unwarranted then?

Comment: @Shaun: Tags have relatively well-defined uses. It's not "Oh, I feel it fits, then it fits". If a question doesn't fit the tag, then it doesn't fit the tag. Period. This is not a question about foundations of mathematics, nor it is about the philosophy of mathematics. Much like the fact people tag puzzle questions with [logic] doesn't mean that these questions fit there.

Comment: @Asaf Karagina: But this fits those tags. It might have been such a question; we know now that it's not intended to, but it *did* at the time I suggested it *sans* Adam's clarification. I'm aware of the purpose of tags. I wouldn't suggest so many if I wasn't.

Comment: I suppose it is my mistake. I could have written: give me proof of this. But I didnt want to be so impolite and presumptuous that there really is a need for a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec v$ (the vertex), $\vec a$, $\vec b$ (the rays) of an angle in $\boldsymbol R^2$.  The interior $I$ of the angle may be defined as $I:=\{\vec v+t\cdot\vec a+s\cdot\vec b\mid t,s\in\boldsymbol R_+\cup\{0\}\}$. Can you go from here?

Comment: Nope, I dont see how one would continue this.

Comment: Maybe find an equation for the outside as well and then show that any point must go into outside or inside?

Comment: I tried for fun to compute some points of that interior from your definition but I came across a following problem. You write that v is a vertex and a and b are rays (in other words geometrical figures) but in your definition of interior they obviously represent numbers. What am I missing?

Comment: @Adam I've just tried to clarify my answer.  Define the exterior of the angle to be $\boldsymbol R\setminus I$.

Comment: I finally kinda see where your approach is going.

Comment: But doesnt your solution kind of pressupose that there is a single region called exterior?

Comment: I mean we have a very good definition of interior but maybe apart from interior there are two regions exterior1 and exterior2, we know that this is not the case, but dont we need to prove it?

Comment: @Adam I can't see two exteriors ... Just draw a picture. The interior is a “cone” with vertex $\Vec

Comment: @Adam I can't see two exteriors ... Just draw a picture. Convince yourself that $I$ is connected.  The interior is a “cone” with vertex $\vec v$ and boundaries  $\vec v+\boldsymbol R_+ \vec a$ and $\vec v+\boldsymbol R_+ \vec b$.  I don't see two different “exteriors”

Comment: Neither do I of course... But the question isnt what you know, but what your proof knows, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Recently I learned about a theorem of topology that says that the complement of a connected region is connected. So this might be a valid proof after all.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem ... Not sure if this is totally correct but I tried using the plane separation axiom (PSA) twice.

Between: undefined (along with point, line, on, and congruent, cf. Hilbert).

Same side: Let $\it{l}$ be a line and let A and B be two points which are not on $\it{l}.$ Points A and B are $\textit{on the same side}$ of $\it{l}$ if either $\it{l}$ and $\leftarrow AB \rightarrow$ do not intersect at all, or if they do intersect but the point of intersection is not between A and B. [cf: Harvey, link below]

PSA: For any line $\it{l}$ and points $A, B, C$ which are not on $\it{l}:$ (i) if A and B are on the same side of $\it{l}$ and A and C are on the same side of $\it{l},$ then B and C are on the same side of $\it{l};$ (ii) If A and B are not on the same side of $\it{l}$ and A and C are not on the same side of $\it{l},$ then B and C are on the same side of $\it{l}.$

The definition of angle interior is

A point lies in the interior or is an interior part of $\angle BAC$ if it is on the same side of AB  as C and the same side of AC as B.

(ref: http://www.mcs.uvawise.edu/msh3e/resources/geometryBook/geometryBook.html)

Here's a diagram:

[image]

Comment: Ad defintion of interior: Basically a definition of an angle using half-planes. I have it in my textbook. Now I noticed the little text in the picture - that seems to be the core part. I will need some time to go through it.

Comment: You write that III is union of not I and not II. Shouldnt that be intersection?

Comment: I believe the argument is correct. I dont say the other one by Michael Hoppe isnt but this one is closer to what I was looking for. And I understand it, which is a nice plus.

Comment: @GregHill Define when “two  point are in the same side”, please.

Comment: I am not Greg Hill, but I would say, they are on the same side if they lie on the same half-plane relative to a certain line. Lets wait what Greg Hill has to say.

Comment: @Adam Then please define when two points lie on the same side of a half plane.

Comment: I suppose you could come up with some kind of inequality of the form ax+by+c > 0. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: I have another definition: lets have two points in the plane and a line. Two points are on the same side iff if you draw a line segment from one point to the other, you cross the line. What do you think?

Comment: @Adam Yes, my mistake using union. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: I updated my post adding undefined term between and def for same side and fixing the error using union instead of intersection.

Comment: I dont understand one thing. Why in the definition of "on the same side" we dont use line segment instead of a line? That way you could avoid using an undefined term of between.

Comment: I don't know & would like to know more of the background myself ... but if it's undefined in Hilbert's axiomatization I'd trust that there was a very good reason.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I dont have any issue with the undefined concept of betweennes, I just question if it is really necessary to use it in this particular definition.

Comment: I see what you mean now .. basically your same side definition would be that segment AB does not intersect $\it{l},$ and then there does not have to be a use of between. I don't immediately see why that wouldn't work ... but I wouldn't be surprised if there is some subtle reason the definition is the way it is.